# Where can I find dimensions of the Lockheed Model 14 Super Electra?

Tags: aircraft-design

I'm doing a school project and I'm trying to find accurate dimensions of the aforementioned aircraft. Is there any website or database that has this information?

Answer (score 5):

(Source): From [this military-history](https://military-history.fandom.com/wiki/Lockheed_Model_14_Super_Electra#Specifications_(Model_14-WF62_Super_Electra)) website:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia states the following:

Length: 44 ft 4 in (13.51 m)

Wingspan: 65 ft 6 in (19.96 m)

Height: 11 ft 5 in (3.48 m)

Since schools don't like Wikipedia, I guess I'll have to find another source to confirm the dimensions.

Edit: ["The Encyclopedia of Military Aircraft"](https://archive.org/details/encyclopediaofmi0000jack) gives the following dimensions for the Ki-56:

Length: 48 ft 11 in (14.9 m)

Wingspan: 65 ft 6 in (19.96 m)

Height: 11 ft 10 in (3.6 m)

Since the Ki-56 was a copy of the Lockheed 14 Super Electra with a 1.5m stretch, subtracting 1.5 from 14.9 gives 13.4m, which is pretty much the same as what Wikipedia states for the Super Electra.